# Fourier Transforms and Sums

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

Suppose I have the following sum:
$$
\sum_{x = -\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(j) \; e^{i j x} dj
$$
Assuming that everything is sufficiently smooth and convergent, then exchanging the sum with the integral gives:
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(j) \; \sum_{x = -\infty}^{\infty} e^{i j x} dj = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(j) \; 2 \pi \delta(j) \; dj = 2 \pi f(0) 
$$
Now suppose that instead I have half infinite sum:
$$
\sum_{x = 1}^{\infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(j) \; e^{i j x} dj
$$
If $ f $ is even, ie. $ f(j) = f(-j) $ then I exploit this by symmetrizing and adding in $ x = 0 $ to find:
$$
\sum_{x = 1}^{\infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(j) \; e^{i j x} dj = \pi f(0) - \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(j) dj 
$$
I'm stumped on the case if $ f $ is odd. I can't seem to find anything useful, which feels unbelievable. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: why would that be a problem ? and in your last formula you meant $-\frac12\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(j) dj$

Comment: Are you asking me how this problem arises? And yes, thank you for pointing out the typo.

Comment: and if $f$ is $2 \pi$ periodic, $C^1$ and $f(0) = 0$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) e^{-i  n x} dx = \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{f(x) e^{-ix/2}}{-4 i \pi \sin(x/2)} dx$. furthermore, if $f(x)$ is constant then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) e^{-i  n x} dx  = 0$ hence if $f$ is $2 \pi$ periodic and $C^1$ : $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) e^{-i  n x} dx = \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{(f(x)-c_0) e^{-ix/2}}{-4 i \pi \sin(x/2)} dx$ where $c_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) dx$ is the mean value of $f$

Comment: Thank you. How does one arrive at that formula? Can you post it as an answer so I can give you some credit?

Comment: I'm just noticing that when $f$ is $C^1$ and $f(0) = 0$, everything converges and you can consider instead $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) \sum_{n=1}^\infty (e^{-ix-\epsilon})^n dx$

Comment: Duh! Yes that makes a lot of sense. Thank you. I wish you would post these as an answer so I could give you some credit.

Comment: (I made a mistake, the $1/(2\pi)$ should be removed (at first I was thinking to the Fourier series inversion theorem..))

Comment: It turns out my function is not $ C^1 $. Can you point me to a reference for how to derive these formulas?

Comment: no, I can only tell you to look at the absolute/monotone/dominated convergence theorems. consider $h(y) = \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{f(x)}{y e^{ix} - 1} dx$. if $f(x) \sim C x$ at $0$, then $h(y)$ is well-defined for every $y \in \mathbb{R}$, and is continuous around $y = 1$ (as $ \frac{f(x)}{y e^{ix} - 1} dx \to \frac{f(x)}{e^{ix} - 1}$). choosing $y > 1$ let you expand $\frac{1}{y e^{ix} -1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty y^{-n} e^{-inx}$ and interverting $\sum$ and $\int$ by absolute or dominated convergence

Comment: you could also look to how the Dirichlet conditions for the convergence of Fourier series are derived, as it is very close to that (and it is exactly what you do in your first formulas, inverting $\sum$ and  $\int$ and replacing $\sum_n e^{inx}$ by $2\pi \delta(x)$). and what is your non $C^1$ function ?